# Highcharts Spline intersection on Y axis Interval line

Tags: highcharts, spline

I want information on how to mark or Highlight point of intersection of between SPline on Y Aaxis interval line.

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwziN.png)

For more information please see picture below:

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwhRi.png)

Comment: You could add a separate scatter series at those points. Knowing where they are a certain value would need to be calculated of course.

Comment: Hello @wergeld , I tried calculation but it is not workings. Is there any way to get data from highchart API ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't support it.